# Easy wait script

Tags: c#, asp.net, timer, webforms, wait

I'm trying to implement in my web form an easy wait function, it works, but not as I would.
My code is this:

```
    for(int i = 0; i<5; i++)
    {
        Label1.Text = "Invio: " +i;
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(6000);
    }
```

The problem is that Label Text doesnt' change every 6 seconds.

This script should use 30second and change the label text in this manner:

"Invio: i" every 6 seconds.

Instead it waits 6 seconds and then it change the text in "Invio 4".

Why?

Comment: Are you using Windows or Web forms ?

Comment: I'm using onyl what u see. I have a web page with only a Label, nothing else!

Comment: So that means u are using Web forms. :)

Comment: You need to learn how the web works! When you make a request, it executes _all_ of your code before returning _anything_ back to the browser. See [asp.net](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/asp.net/info), in particular [ASP.NET Page Life Cycle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.ASPX)

Comment: Checkout my fiddle in the edited answer. Advise if you want to achieve this with frond-end technique or a back-end one. If you trying to refresh the page every 'n' seconds you can do this with the example given by Dmitri, if you want to achieve a refresh-less updating of the page - you can use either javascript/jquery or if you need it for more advance tasks as to gather some information from the server every 'n' seconds you can check out the [ICallbackEventHandler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.icallbackeventhandler.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason this happens is because of the view state . Before you render your page the back-end code is executed, after it finishes, the DOM start to render and then your page is ready. That means your page won't refresh the label value every N seconds, because it has been already set. If you want to change the value of this dynamically you should use some front-end method as JavaScript or jQuery. If you want this approach - comment so I can make a fiddle for you.
Also this would be helpful for you - [ViewState](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972976.aspx)

Here is a fiddle to check if you want something like this - [Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Y2FcT/6/)

```
 var count = 1;
time = setInterval(function(){

    document.getElementById("label1").innerHTML="Indio: " + count;
    count+= 1;
    if (count == 5)
    {
        clearInterval(time);
    }
},6000);
```

Comment: Good, I need that it stops when count == 5. How I can do it?

Answer (score 0):

Back end like this:

```
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }

    protected void Timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Label txt = Label1;

        int i = Convert.ToInt32(txt.Text);

        if (i == 4)
        {
            Timer1.Enabled = false;
        }
        else
        {
            i++;
            Label1.Text = i.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

and front-end is like this:

```
<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
    </asp:ScriptManager>
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <asp:Timer ID="Timer1" runat="server" OnTick="Timer1_Tick" Enabled="true" Interval="6000">
            </asp:Timer>
            <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="Invio: "></asp:Label>
            <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="0"></asp:Label>
        </ContentTemplate>
        <Triggers>
            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="Timer1" />
        </Triggers>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
</asp:Content>
```

This will loop 5 times with a 6 second interval.

Timer on page will trigger a postback, server side will execute and will update an updatepanel.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there is no easy way of doing that kind of thing purely using basic Asp.Net webforms (unless you use Asp.Net Webforms AJAX - which I personally find very confusing).

Assuming you are trying to provide some feed back to your user, about a long running operation, I'd use a combination of javascript (using JQuery Ajax for example) and a simple page to poll if the task is done, then redirect to result page.